# junit cleanup test data in object level

Tags: java, testing, junit

I'm new to junit.

I like to create some artifacts in DB before all the tests run and delete them afterward. but I can't use `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` because they are static, my runner will run my cases in parellel so I need it per-object.

I'd imagine there are sort of non static `setup()`/ `teardown()` methods I can override in my cases, but could not find it.

What's the common practice for this situation?

--EDIT--

@Before and @After are not good as well. The per test creation and deletion will be an issue to the system

Comment: read about `@Before` and `@After` but that refer toan test casenot the complete test class. Also take a lookat [DbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: You want a way for several Objects to share the setup and teardown, but you can't use the static methods?

Comment: I think you can create a BaseClass and in the constructor you can initialise/create your artifacts and in the finalize method you can delete them.
And if you want to create the artifacts class-wise then you can create it in its own constructor and have a finalize method.

Comment: You would see to [database-rider](https://github.com/database-rider).

Comment: Can you have a look at this  http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/ to see if it fits your needs? It provides you with the ability to set your database the way you like before each test. (Also if you are using spring there is an annotation that enhance this tool also )

Comment: @Scratte no. I want a way for the methods in same object share things, and I want to be sure the thing is cleaned up when the tests are done. Destructor in C++ pretty much what I need but not availabe in Java.

Comment: Thanks everyone for mentioning dbunit or database-rider, I will look into them but my artifacts are not only in DB, so I'm still searching.

Comment: @Aman finalize() don't always get called. Actually in my case, since the tester process get created and terminated very soon, I would expect that they rarely get called.